# ASP MVC Unit testing a paged list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Say I have a controller which looks something like the one below where I fetch some items out of a database and add them to a paged list. How would I go about writing a unit test for this? I can't seem to find any good material on this.

Controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ErrorModel Errors { get; set; }
    public List<ErrorModel> ErrorList { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Error(int? page)
    {
        string cs = "Data Source=" + "some\\path";

        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(cs))
        {
            var listOfErrors = new List<ErrorModel>();
            string stm = "SELECT * FROM Error WHERE Checked == 'False'";
            con.Open();

            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, con))
            {
                using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        listOfErrors.Add(new ErrorModel
                        {
                            Id = rdr["ID"].ToString(),
                            Type = rdr["Type"].ToString(),
                        });
                    }

                    rdr.Close();
                    ErrorList = listOfErrors;
                }
            }

            con.Close();
        }

        // stuff for paging
        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1); // if there is no page, return page 1

        return View(ErrorList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

My current, obviously not adequate unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class ErrorControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestErrorView()
    {
        var controller = new ErrorController();
        var result = controller.Error(1) as ViewResult;
        Assert.AreEqual("Error", result.ViewName);
    }
}
```

Any hints greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to test? The database result? The controller action?

If you are serious about trying to test this, you might have more luck abstracting out your data retrieval/business logic and unit testing that independently of the MVC action.  If your business method is doing it's job (according to the tests) you don't need to test that MVC will return the result.

```
public ActionResult Error(int? page)
{
    var model = _privateObjForReturningStuff.GetPage(page);
    return View(model);
}

public class ForReturningStuff
{
    public Model GetPage(int page)
    {
        ... gets page stuff
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ForReturningStuffTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetPage_does_something_I_can_assert()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Typically, you wouldn't unit test 3rd party code.

Comment: If you want some as-real-as-possible use cases for unit tests, try this project https://odetofood.codeplex.com/.  It contains an application and it's supporting tests so you can get an idea of how you could unit test controllers and other bits/bobs.